# How do I create a strongly typed mapped literal against an existing type with nested indices?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I think I may be bumping up against an open bug (https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21760) with typescript but i'm effectively trying to figure out how to create mapped literal types from other literal constants.

Think the correct indexed typed result from the below lodash function.

const result = _.mapKeys(en, x => x.display);

```js
export const en = {
    ACTIVE: {
        ordinal: 0,
        display: 'Active',
    },
    INACTIVE: {
        ordinal: 1,
        display: 'Inactive',
    },
} as const;

// how do i type this?
export const displayToEnum = {};

// actual runtime implementation code
for (const key in en) {
    displayToEnum[en[key].display] = en[key];
}


// What i've tried

type Displays = typeof en[keyof typeof en]['display']

type DisplayToEnum = { 
    // how do i do this dynamically - find the mapped item which fits the conditional constraint
    [P in Displays]: P extends typeof en['ACTIVE']['display'] ? typeof en['ACTIVE'] : typeof en['INACTIVE'];
}

export const displayToEnum: DisplayToEnum = {} as any;

for (const key in en) {
    displayToEnum[en[key].ordinal] = en[key];
}

// its hardcoded, but this resolves correctly to 0.
const value = displayToEnum['Active'].ordinal;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Extract` to filter the values of `en` based on the current property `P`

```
export const en = {
    ACTIVE: {
        ordinal: 0,
        display: 'Active',
    },
    INACTIVE: {
        ordinal: 1,
        display: 'Inactive',
    },
} as const;

type En = typeof en

type DisplayEnum = {
    [P in En[keyof En]['display']]: Extract<En[keyof En], { display: P }>
}
```

Or you can use something like `UnionToIntersection` to build the type from a union where each member contains one property with the same name as the `display`

```
type UnionToIntersection<U> = 
(U extends any ? (k: U)=>void : never) extends ((k: infer I)=>void) ? I : never

type DisplayEnum2 = UnionToIntersection<{
    [P in keyof En]: Record<En[P]['display'], En[P]>
}[keyof En]>;
```